# How to rotate 2 rectangles in a canvas at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I know that I can use the "translate-rotate-translate back-fillrect" procedure to rotate one single rectangle.

However, what if I want to rotate them both at the same time and have a timeinterval() to make them rotate automatically every second?

I tried to save and restore each time I try to draw, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You appear to be on the right track!**

- Save
- Translate(rectX,rectY)
- Rotate
- fillRect(-rectWidth/2,-rectHeight/2,rectWidth,rectHeight) // draws the rect w/ center rotation
- Restore

**For multiple Rectangles**

If you define some rectangle objects like this:

```
var rects=[];
rects.push({x:50,y:50,w:50,h:35,color:'green',angle:0});
rects.push({x:150,y:120,w:30,h:20,color:'blue',angle:0});
```

Then you can put them in an animation frame like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
    // call for another loop in the animation
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // clear canvas and redraw all rects
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
        // draw this rect at its specified angle
        var rect=rects[i];
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(rect.x+rect.w/2,rect.y+rect.h/2);
        ctx.rotate(rect.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle=rect.color;
        ctx.fillRect(-rect.w/2,-rect.h/2,rect.w,rect.h);
        ctx.restore();

        // increase this rect's angle for next time
        rect.angle+=(Math.PI*2)/60;
    }
}
```

`requestAnimationFrame` loops at about 60fps so if you increment the rect's angle in each loop by (Math.PI*2)/60 you will rotate the rect about one full turn every second.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var rects=[];
rects.push({x:50,y:50,w:50,h:35,color:'green',angle:0});
rects.push({x:150,y:120,w:30,h:20,color:'blue',angle:0});

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  // call for another loop in the animation
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  // clear canvas and redraw all rects
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    // draw this rect at its specified angle
    var rect=rects[i];
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(rect.x+rect.w/2,rect.y+rect.h/2);
    ctx.rotate(rect.angle);
    ctx.fillStyle=rect.color;
    ctx.fillRect(-rect.w/2,-rect.h/2,rect.w,rect.h);
    // orientation symbol
    ctx.fillStyle='red';
    ctx.fillRect(-rect.w/2,-rect.h/2,5,5)
    ctx.restore();

    // increase this rect's angle for next time
    rect.angle+=(Math.PI*2)/60;
  }
}

function drawRect(rect){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(rect.x+rect.w/2,rect.y+rect.h/2);
  ctx.rotate(rect.angle);
  ctx.fillStyle=rect.color;
  ctx.fillRect(-rect.w/2,-rect.h/2,rect.w,rect.h);
  ctx.restore();
  rect.angle+=deltaAngle;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```